# How to show some model in a modal?

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I'm tring to pass some data contained in a table to a modal , let's say a row .

Here is the code i wrote

HTML:

```
<td>
    <a ng-if="row.vat_list.length > 1" href="#/someUrl" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vatModal" ng-click="setRow(row)">{{row.vat_list[0].vat_number}}</a>
```

This is the setRow:

```
$scope.setRow = function (row){
                    $scope.row= row;
                };
```

and this is the directive i wrote to open the modal:

```
 .directive('modalDialog', function(DISPATCHER_BROADCAST) {
          return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                row: '='
            },
            transclude: true, 
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            },
            templateUrl: 'modules/dispatcher/modal.tpl.html' 
          };
        });
```

and this is the template of the modal :

```
<div id="vatModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{ 'STORIC_VAT' | translate}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="table-responsive" style="overflow-x:visible;" >
            <table class="table" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-order">{{'VAT_NUMBER' | translate}}</th>
                        <th class="col-order">{{'CUSTOMER_DENOMINATION'| translate}}</th>
                        <th class="col-order">{{'START_DATE'| translate}}</th>
                        <th class="col-order">{{'END_DATE'| translate}}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                    <tr ng-repeat="row in row.vat_list">
                        <td>{{row.vat_number}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.customer_denomination}}</p></td>
                        <td>{{row.start_date}}</td>
                        <td>{{row.end_date}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

and this is how i declare my modal:

```
    <modal-dialog ng-model="row"></modal-dialog>
```

basically here it seems that my directive is not able to bind the scope of the controller to the scope of the directive, so my table in the modal has only the headers, without any dinamic model

Any hint? Where did i get wrong?

EDIT:

here is my HTML sample:

```
 <td>
    <a ng-if="row.vat_list.length > 1" href="#/dispatcher/spot" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vatModal" ng-click="setRow(row)">{{row.vat_list[0].vat_number}}
        <modal-dialog row="row"></modal-dialog>
    </a>
        </td>
```

Basically if i try to debug, i see that when page load, directive is loaded, bit when i click on my link, there's no interaction with the directive

Comment: How are you open `modalDialog` directive?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko i updated my question, i forgot to add my directive

Comment: Try `<modal-dialog row="row"></modal-dialog>`

Comment: still doesn't show any model, just headers of the table

Comment: Maybe you have error in console?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko   no errors and no alerts

Answer (score 0):

Well, i reproduce your code anf it works fine.

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/hxmxqvbd/)

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.rows = [{
      vat_list: [{
        name: "vat 0"
      }]
    }, {
      vat_list: [{
        name: "vat 1"
      }, {
        name: "vat 11"
      }, {
        name: "vat 12"
      }]
    }, {
      vat_list: [{
        name: "vat 2"
      }, {
        name: "vat 21"
      }, {
        name: "vat 22"
      }]
    }, {
      vat_list: [{
        name: "vat 3"
      }]
    }, ];

    vm.setRow = function(row) {
      vm.row = row;
    };
  })
  .directive('modalDialog', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        row: '='
      },
      transclude: true,
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {},
      template: `<h3>Modal dialog</h3>
            <table ng-if="row">
                    <tr ng-repeat="row in row.vat_list">
                       <td>{{row.name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>`
    };
  });;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <div ng-repeat="row in vm.rows">
      <a href="#" ng-click="vm.setRow(row)">{{row.vat_list[0].name}}</a>
    </div>
    <modal-dialog row="vm.row"></modal-dialog>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: debugging the code it seems that the main problem is that i declare the directive INSIDE the html , so is instantiated and when i click on my link, it does not bind the scope

Comment: How are you declare directive INSIDE html?

Comment: @Anon Well, move `<modal-dialog row="row"></modal-dialog>` from `ng-repeat`